# Dúvida com LEFT ou INNER JOIN e WHERE SQL Access

Tags: sql, query, join, microsoft-access, where

tudo bem?

Então, eu tenho essa query aqui no Access:

```
SELECT tbl_produtos.NomeProduto, tbl_produtos.PrecoVenda, tbl_precos_especiais.PrecoVenda
FROM tbl_produtos LEFT JOIN tbl_precos_especiais ON tbl_precos_especiais.ID_Produto = tbl_produtos.ID_Produto;
```

[image: Os resultados são esses]

Porém na tbl_precos_especiais, tem um campo ID_CLiFor, e eu quero colocar um WHERE no fim da query para filtrar os resultados por esse campo:

```
SELECT tbl_produtos.NomeProduto, tbl_produtos.PrecoVenda, tbl_precos_especiais.PrecoVenda
FROM tbl_produtos LEFT JOIN tbl_precos_especiais ON tbl_precos_especiais.ID_Produto = tbl_produtos.ID_Produto WHERE tbl_precos_especiais.ID_CliFor = 268;
```

Porém, ele trás apenas os resultados onde na tbl_precos_especiais o ID_CliFor é 268:
[image: Resultados com WHERE]

Mas eu queria que ele trouxesse todos os resultados da tbl_produtos também. É que na tbl_precos_especiais vai ter vários ID_CliFor, e eu vou filtrar para o cliente específico o que ele já tem nessa tabela mas também os produtos que ainda não tem para que possam ser adicionados dados.

Não entendo muito de SQL e apreciaria uma ajuda.

Grato

Fabio

Comment: "Porém, ele trás apenas os resultados onde na tbl_precos_especiais o ID_CliFor é 268" é óbvio pois você colocou a cláusula `WHERE tbl_precos_especiais.ID_CliFor = 268`. Explique o que você quer dizer com "... mas também os produtos que ainda não tem para que possam ser adicionados dados". Não tem o produto onde?

Answer (score 1):

Fabio, o valor da coluna ID_CliFor da tabela tbl_precos_especiais será nulo quando não houver uma linha nessa tabela para o produto já que está sendo utilizado Left Join, então experimente deixar o Where da seguinte forma:

```
WHERE tbl_precos_especiais.ID_CliFor = 268 OR tbl_precos_especiais.ID_CliFor IS NULL;
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: boa, funcionou, obrigado!